# ABC PDF - create 256 color images

Tags: abcpdf

I am using ABCpdf7 to create pdf documents on the fly - Here is something that I do not understand. When I create the pdf document from a url - the images in the pdf document seems to be 256 colors.

Does anyone know how I can set ABCpdf to create full color images.

If I spesify the image url - the image gets created at full color - but then I cannot crab a page in one go

Comment: This is very specific to the ABCpdf product... have you tried their forums/support?

Comment: I have tried the forum and support and have send them a email - thanks Dave - It seems like there is this option to set it theDoc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 100 but it does not seem to work and the image files remain at 256 colors...

Answer (score 2):

24 Hours later and I have finally found the answer to the question - The problem is the actual screencard (hardware) installed on my computer.

I tested the software locally on my computer which have a 32bit screencard and the pdf's looks perfect.

On the 16bit server screencard it does not look good and get's reduced to 256 colors!